# AJAX : How to get info about permission reject

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an ASP.NET MVC application, where I call method by AJAX:

```
        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "/Admin/AllowVideoUpload",
            type: "POST",
            data: { val: val },
            error: function () {
                alert('Error');
            }
        });
```

if success - nothing happens on client side, if error - get 'Error' message. But error can be by different reasons - problem inside "AllowVideoUpload" method or user lost his credentials (AdminController has attribute 'Authorize(Roles = "Admin")'). I want to differ these 2 types of error. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Those are your application level errors. So it should be handled in the success handler.

You may return  `json` from your action method which has a Status /Error code/Message element where you mention what is the error reason.

**Sample Json for Error**

```
{
    "Status": "Failed",
    "Message": "Authentication Failed"
}
```

**Sample Json for Success**

```
{
    "Status": "Success",
    "Message": "Successfully Updated"
}
```

Read the jSon and then you can decide what to do next.may be show message to user

```
$.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: "/Admin/AllowVideoUpload",
        type: "POST",
        data: { val: val },
        success:function(data){
           if(data.Status=="Success")
           {
               //operation success. do whatever
           }
           else if(data.Status=="Failed")
           {
             alert(data.Message);
           }
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('Error');
        }
});
```

Comment: @user285336: Your Application specific errors. The jQuery ajax error event is for handling errors occured while making an ajax call(ex: request failed etc..). Whatever you mentioned is your application level errors.

Comment: it can be other reason of error, ie user leaves page before ending of execute ajax call. "error" section will be called. I want to differ auth problem from other.

Comment: in any case not understand how to separate auth error from not completed ajax call for example